# conflict between overlay and ifelse functions in r-raster

Tags: r, r-raster

I was running a code and found a weird behaviour when using an `ifelse` function inside an `overlay` in the raster package. In short, the function will report an error if the first 5 values of every raster is `NA`. 
Why is that happening? 
Below is a short code that mimics the problem I found using R 3.2.3 and raster version 2.5-2, and some temporary solutions that I'm thinking on using meanwhile.

Thanks

Carlos Albero

```
library(raster)
cob1d <- raster(matrix(1,nr=6,nc=6))
cob1 <- cob1d; cob2 <- cob1d; cob3 <- cob1d
overlay(cob1, cob2, cob3, fun=function(x1, x2, x3)  ifelse(x1 > 0, x1 + x2 + x3,  x3))

# class       : RasterLayer 
# dimensions  : 6, 6, 36  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
# resolution  : 0.1666667, 0.1666667  (x, y)
# extent      : 0, 1, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : NA 
# data source : in memory
# names       : layer 
# values      : 3, 3  (min, max)


# Changing the first 5 values...

cob1[1:5] <- NA; cob2[1:5] <- NA; cob3[1:5] <- NA
overlay(cob1, cob2, cob3, fun=function(x1, x2, x3)  (x1 + x2 + x3))
```

gave the same result...

```
# but if I use `ifelse`, there is a problem:

overlay(cob1, cob2, cob3, fun=function(x1, x2, x3)  ifelse(x1 > 0, x1 + x2 + x3,  x3))
# Error in ifelse(x1, x1 + x2 + x3, x3) : 
#  argument "x2" is missing, with no default 

# Another way to solve it is adding a useless extra variable without `NA`.

cob4 <- cob1d
overlay(cob1, cob2, cob3, cob4, fun=function(x1, x2, x3, x4)  ifelse(x1 > 0, x1 + x2 + x3,  x3))
# same result as before...
# class       : RasterLayer 
# dimensions  : 6, 6, 36  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
# resolution  : 0.1666667, 0.1666667  (x, y)
# extent      : 0, 1, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : NA 
# data source : in memory
# names       : layer 
# values      : 3, 3  (min, max)

# or just avoiding the use of the `ifelse` function...

overlay(cob1, cob2, cob3, cob4, fun=function(x1, x2, x3, x4)  (x1 > 0) * (x1 + x2 + x3) + (x1 <= 0)*x3)
```

Comment: I am getting the same error. Not sure why though...

Comment: are you also using an `ifelse` function? can you copy the function you're using or a simplified version of it?

Comment: I just tried out your code and got the same error messages. However I really don't understand this strange behaviour using the ifelse function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an interesting case. `overlay` uses the first 5 cells to determine how to process the data (via `apply` or via `do.call`). The first test is to see if `apply` can be used. The function used can be run via `apply` if all values are `NA`

```
f <- function(x1, x2, x3)  ifelse(x1 > 0, x1 + x2 + x3,  x3)
m <- matrix(NA, 5, 3)
apply(m, 1, f)
```

Based on that test, `apply` is used for all cells. However, `apply` fails with this function when not all values are `NA`:

```
m[1] <- 1
apply(m, 1, f)
```

This fails, because only has one first argument `x` (not three arguments as `f` requires).

Whereas the *opposite* case is common (a function that fail when only `NA` values are supplied) this case is rare.

`raster:::calc` has the argument `forcefun` to avoid using `apply`, but this is not available in `overlay`. I have added that to future versions of `raster` (version >= 2.5-4), such that you can do:

```
f <- function(x1, x2, x3)  ifelse(x1 > 0, x1 + x2 + x3,  x3)
overlay(cob1, cob2, cob3, fun=f, forcefun=TRUE)
```

In any case, you can use `calc` as a work-around:

```
s <- stack(cob1, cob2, cob3)
r <- calc(s, fun=function(x)  ifelse(x[1] > 0, x[1] + x[2] + x[3],  x[3]))
```

Or another alternative, based on your alternative function:

```
r <- (cob1 > 0) * (cob1 + cob2 + cob3) + (cob1 <= 0)*cob3
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to use every "x" in your function with a condition, e.g.

```
overlay(cob1, cob2, cob3, fun=function(x1, x2, x3)  ifelse(x1 > 0 & x2 >0 & x3 >0 , x1 + x2 + x3,  x3))
```

not only the condition for `x1` (`x1>0`)